# How to change the property type with minimum code edit?

Tags: java, oop

I have a custom class `Bus` with field `int number`. The constructor therefore takes an `int` when a new object is created.

```
class Bus {
    int number;
    Bus(int n) {
        number = n;
    }
}
```

There are a few objects created using the constructor seen above.
`Bus bus = new Bus(21);` and so on.

Now I wish to change datatype to `String` instead of `int`.
If I simply change the datatype in `Bus` class, I'll have to change all the objects I've already created which will be a lot of work if there are hundreds of objects.

I wish to know if there is any easier and smarter way to make these changes and avoid a lot of work. Or is there a better way to implement the class so that such changes would be easy to make?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add one another constructor in Bus class and keep the existing one:

```
String number;

Bus(int n) {
    this( String.valueof(n) ); // or do other thing, as you need
}

Bus(String n) {
    number = n;
}
```

But may be it is not a good idea. If you can, you should remove the old constructor and do a complete refactor for each existing calls. Doing that, you avoid maintaining code which is not used anymore. If you can't do this, consider keeping the previous constructor and using @deprecated annotation to keep in mind to not use it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Just convert the int in the constructor.

```
class Bus {

    String number;

    Bus(int n) {
        this(Integer.toString(n));
    }

    Bus(String n) {
        number = n;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can chose an object Higher in the object hierarchy than both int and string, for example object. You can then manipulate that object as you will in each method.

```
public class HelloWorld{
     public Object n;
     public HelloWorld(Object n){
         this.n = n;
     }
     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        HelloWorld magic = new HelloWorld(23);
        System.out.print(magic.n);System.out.print("\n");
     }
}
```

Honestly an O O Design professional would bite my head off... 
prints::

```
HelloWorld                                          
23
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are ok to change the datatype, simply convert in same constructor.

```
class Bus {
   String number;
   Bus(int n) {
      number = String.valueOf(n);
   }
}
```